# Iterating through two lists, operating and creating a third list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, comparison

I am a completely Python beginner and am really struggling with iterations on Lists! 
There's this problem I have been trying to solve using python using Lists:

I have a "**TotalList**" for the total costs on each hour for a product:

Hr  totalcost
1   100
2   50
...
24  150

And I have **minList** which has the % of the total cost in that hour for that minute

Hr  Min    (%) Cost
1    1     1.0
1    2     5.0
...
2    1     2.0
2    2     4.0
...
24   1     2.3

I want to evaluate **for each hour** the total cost in every minute and put it in a third list. That list **minuteCost** would look like this:

Hr  Min    Cost
1    1     totalList [0][2] *  minList [0][2]
1    2     totalList [1][2] *  minList [1][2]
...
2    1     xxx
2    2     xxx
...
24   1     xxx

I am sure there's an easy way to do this! Any suggestion would be much appreciated! I would also appreciate solutions based on numpy.

Comment: Show us your code and what problems you are running into.

Comment: You aren't really iterating over 2 lists, you are iterating over the minute list and looking up in the `hour` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary from your total cost list and compute the minute costs by referencing the total cost at each hour (from the dict) and multiplying by the percentage minute cost.

A *list comprehension* will do:

```
tc_mapping = dict(totalList) # map hour to cost
minute_cost = [(h, m, percent * tc_mapping[h]) for h, m, percent in minList]
```

Comment: @Pescador You may consider accepting if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest for a beginner to understand IMO:

```
minuteCost = []
x = 0
for i in minList:
    tempList = [i[0], i[1], totalList[x][1]*i[2]]
    minuteCost.append(tempList)
    x += 1
```

This assumes that TotalList and minList are the same length.

Comment: But they aren't the same length, `minList` (many entries per hour) is much bigger than `totalList` (one entry per hour). Just convert `totalList` to a dictionary of `{hour: totalcost}` then just look up based on `i[0]`.

Comment: This is true. I overlooked that part. Dictionary will be the best option then.